# Arc Length with x as a limit

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I'm stuck on a problem that deals with arc length. I know how to calculate the arc length in general, but I seem to have forgotten what to do in this particular situation. I know it's simple, but my book barely explains it, and I have failed to find any information online. Any help would be great!

$$
y =\int_1^x\sqrt{t^2-1}  \ dt  \ , 4\leq x \leq 7
$$

Answer = $$33/2$$

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to solve this, I would be thrilled!

Comment: This question is definitely ill defined. What is $x$ here? Do you have any context from the book? I would presume $x$ is a real number between $4$ and $7$ inclusive due to it being an integration limit,  but this just gives a set of possible answers

Comment: This was all that was given, that's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

We  need to find 
$$\int_4^7\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx.$$

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x^2-1}$.

Square, add $1$, take the square root. We end up with something quite simple.

Comment: WOW! That was easy! I knew it was something simple, but I just couldn't recall it. Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: @CarterHunt: You are welcome.